# Windows 7 boot animation looks like vista

Tags: windows-7, resolution

Why is my windows 7 boot animation just a Microsoft logo with a progress bar? (just like vista's). I installed this on a desktop and is the same dvd that I used for my desktop. Is it because of the 1024x600 resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Windows 7 bootlogo requires 768 vertical pixels.